# Writing to csv file from PHP array displaying code instead of array values

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm trying to input data from csv to a php array, do some calculations and sort the data then write the new output back into csv from the array ready to go from a download button.

Here's what I've got:

```
f(isset($_POST["download_csv"])){
  $fileName = 'csv-report.csv';

  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Pragma: public");

  $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

  foreach ( $table as $subids => $values ) {
      // Put the data into the stream
      fputcsv($fh, $values);
  }
  // Close the file
  fclose($fh);
  // Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
  exit;
}
```

For some reason, it's giving me code in the csv file that downloads and no values. It's confusing because when I use just this part written this way to write to a csv file in the root directory it works just fine and gives expected output:

```
$fh = @fopen( 'csv-report.csv', 'w' );

  foreach ( $table as $subids => $values ) {
      // Put the data into the stream
      fputcsv($fh, $values);
  }
  // Close the file
  fclose($fh);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT1:

[this is what I mean by its giving me code in the csv output instead of the array values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPd7W.png) When I remove the post check it's giving me the values properly but it's now in the middle of a bunch of html.

Comment: I made a version with some sample data and removing the `POST` check and everything is working as expected for me. https://3v4l.org/ZXpG7 (They won't send headers from that site so a download doesn't happen but you'll see that the data is there still)

Comment: You're sure you have PHP tag and file is .php? That's about the only reasons I can think that you would see "code".

Comment: `giving me code`...what code exactly? You mean your PHP code? Be specific please. Give an example if it's easier.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the output. I've now removed the post check and it is displaying the values in cvs properly but in the middle of a bunch of html.

Comment: In short, above the `if` statement there's some HTML that is also being echoed to the stream. The statement `fopen( 'php://output', 'w' )` doesn't create a new stream, it keeps writing to the same stream.

Comment: I suggest moving the code you've shown either to the top of your script (because it will exit after doing that bit) or into a different script entirely.